# Two unrelated circuits drop at the same time

Tags: electrical, circuit

I'm writing a new post for a couple of reason, 1) the post I found that was similar was more than 5 years old and 2) I was not able to comment because I don't have "50 reputation points"

So here's what I have. 2 circuits in my house drop at the same time. This used to happen once in a while, tonight it has happened about 5 times.
As I have UPSs on one of the circuits I'm able to log that the power drops for 4 seconds each time, then comes back. No flicker at any time, just off and back on

The confusing thing to me is they are on opposite legs of the 200 amp service and the best I can tell at the moment is nothing else on either side seems to be affected, just these 2 circuits.

What the heck could / should I be looking at here. It makes no sense.
In my UPS logs I see, utility failure 3 seconds and Invert 3 seconds. I presume the Invert means it was inverted to battery for that time.

All other monitoring looks good meaning I don't see any voltage sags or spikes. No under or Over voltage incidents and no Boost or Buck incidents.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What make and model is your main panel? Are these two circuits fed from completely separate breakers, or two poles of the same breaker?

Comment: It's an older Bryant panel I believe. They are totally separate breakers. One is a brand new Square D Homeline breaker and the other is one of the original breakers in the panel, I suspect Bryant. At least I think it's Bryant.

The house was built in 1948. I do not know when this panel was installed.
I do know the drop from the pole to the house is about 18 years old. That got replaced shortly after I moved in. That new triplex goes as far as the outside service disconnect beaker just after the meter

Comment: Can you post photos of the panel please, and point out which breakers in the panel the failing circuits are on?

Comment: Include a picture of the identification label in the panel showing all the make/model and tech specs of the panel.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel and Freeman. I do not see a way to attach images here. Here is a link to them in my GoogleDrive
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DgZP7QgFTSPKEIRuE1s_x73s7BZf44Ke?usp=sharing

Comment: @FreeMan Please see above link. The system here only allows one "tag" per comment

Comment: When you [edit] the post, there is a little "sun & mountain" icon above the text entry box. Click that and it'll open a dialog where you can add images. Or, you can just drag & drop the pic into the text edit box and it'll upload & host it for you. It's true that pictograms are handy because they're international and don't need any translation into other languages - 90% of the time, _nobody_ understands them, no matter what language they speak!

Comment: @FreeMan IDK, maybe I don't have enough "points" or something to attach images but I do not have said icon.
I have the open text box with nothing around it except the Add Comment button to the right.
I've been in IT for more than 25 years and have worked with countless forum software packages but this one, whatever it is or however it's configured is interesting to say the least.
Either way, are you OK with the link, were you able to see the images?

Comment: Wow you need to look inside the panel and check the wiring with the square D hom breakers mixed in a Bryant panel there could be some really wonky stuff going on.  If those 2 breakers go to the same neutral they should be at minimum handle tied but mixing breakers in panels is not a good thing I believe Siemens are listed for Bryant but not so sure about square D hom type.  Code did not require handle ties when this was built but has for a few code cycles. If it is a MWBC

Comment: Everything goes to the same neutral / ground bar on the right. 
HOWEVER, now that you've pointed this out, I do see what may be an issue.
Over there on the right there is part of that bus which has the NEUTRAL leg coming in and then a higher level of that bus tied to the ground.
What's not cool and I never noticed before is, there is a mix of neutral and ground wires for the circuits to each of those and that can not be right

Comment: If you look along the top of the [edit] window, you'll see **B** *I* [weird over-stylized link icon] " {} [mountains and sun icon]<--- that's the "add image" button.  I'm editing in the images, feel free to [edit] again if you don't like that.

Comment: Codewize the ground and neutral being combined or bonded in the main panel is actually a requirement.  Some panels use a bonding jumper normally a heavy copper wire or a green screw that ties the 2 busses together. 
This bond is required in a main panel and this is the only place the 2 are allowed to be tied together to prevent possible parallel paths back from sub panels or devices.

Comment: @EdBeal OK ok good, that eases my mind a bit so maybe I just need to check the neutrals and replace the Square D breakers with Bryant ones, if I can find them.
I always get talked out of replacing this panel LOL. I hate messes.

Comment: What's on that 20A HOM breaker adjacent to the two failing circuits?

Comment: Also, can you get your hands on a decent voltmeter/multimeter?

Answer (score 2):

### On your original problem

Ed Beal is on the right track.  I think it's a "lost neutral", but since we now know the circuits are unrelated, I am highly suspicious of a "lost neutral *for the whole house*.  95% of the time, this is due to a neutral wire failure in the overhead **service drop** line coming from the poletop to your house, which is not your bailiwick, and which the power company fixes for free in almost all cases.

What happens is that on the *service* side of the meter (the power company's side), they do not carry safety ground as a wire.  (it's in the air anyway lol).  They use pre-bundled "triplex" wires like this.  The bare wire is the carrier wire which carries the physical weight of the other 2 wires, and is physically anchored at both ends.

the bare wire is used for both the neutral and the carrier wire (we can't do that; the power company can). Years of whipping in the wind tend to break it.  The neutral fails.    When that happens, the two legs are still 240V, but neutral is no longer *halfway* between them.  So the two 120V legs *still add up* to 240V, but they are no longer 120/120 - they are 105/135 or really, "all over the map".  This changes based on the loads of the appliances on each leg *in that instant*.

This doesn't get as extreme as it could, because neutral has a second path: via the Neutral-Ground Equipotential Bond in your panel, the Grounding Electrode System, **a bunch of dirt**, to  your neighbor's GES and through their N-G bond.  That is about as effective as you'd expect (better than nothing at all, but not great).  However, this can work  *well enough* (especially with LED lighting) that people can go weeks or even months without even realizing they have a problem.

Enter the wildcard: the UPS.  The UPS is actually monitoring power quality closer than anything else in your house (including you).  It's going "Hey, this ain't right".

So my advice is investigate a possible "Lost Neutral", as it nicely conforms with the stated symptoms.   Get a voltmeter and monitor AC voltage (easy mode: get a Kill-A-Watt energy monitor; its first display is instant voltage.)

Now, try turning on large **120V** (plug-in) loads in your house. "Large" means things which make a lot of heat like a hair dryer or toaster.   Watch the voltage. If neutral is in good order, the voltage *anywhere else in the house* should not deviate by more than 1 volt (maybe 2 at the absolute outside).  Shut off all 120V or 120/240V loads (anything that uses neutral), and call the power company and report an outage.

### On that panel

So, driven by this problem, you have a lot of eagerness to fix stuff, but not much knowledge about panels.  You have also been the victim of faulty information sources.  That is fine; we all start there.  Having dealt with plenty of them, here is what I would do if it was my panel and *my* hard-earned:

Bryant is a perfectly respectable panel type.  In the 80s(?) it was acquired by Cutler-Hammer which has been part of Eaton all along.  In recent years Eaton has stepped out of the shadows and started putting their own brand alongside their various brands, sorta like GM sticking their logos on Chevy cars.  Cutler-Hammer and Eaton hasn't made any radical changes to the BR line since they acquired it, outside of no longer using colored handles (the handle colors match traditional Buss fuse colors).

First, the Square D breakers are gone.  They never belonged in the panel in the first place - there are serious safety issues with crossing breaker brands **because the bus stab shapes are different**.  UL, Square D and Eaton all say "don't do that". They get replaced by BR breakers, which are now marketed as Eaton.  Same thing.

As far as being unable to find Eaton BR breakers, that ain't right. BR breakers are the most popular in America.  So you're in an unusual place (like Guam) or just aren't trying very hard lol.

As far as replacing the colored-handle BR breakers, that's really not *indicated* based on trade experience.  We just don't see reports of old BR breakers failing.  There is a general sense of "breakers wear out", and I suppose you could swap in new Eaton BR *if you really want to*... but I'd put it on the safety upgrade D-list, honestly. Other upgrades are more important.

What I would do is turn each breaker off and lift it out of the panel, and look at the bus stabs for any arcing damage, being bent, that kind of thing.  Light oxidation doesn't bother me.  Any stabs that are burned, those get put out-of-service permanently. I wouldn't condemn the whole panel unless problems are severe.

### That safety budget

Since you seem to be willing to spend 4 digits on improving panel safety, here's how I'd prioritize that.

- Any 3-prong dryer or range circuits get upgraded to 4-prong w/ ground, *either* via retrofit ground ($10) *or* using a GFCI breaker ($80).
- GFCI *protection* on all kitchen, bathroom, laundry, garage, basement receptacles, and any water features (pool equipment etc.)  I'd try to do it with GFCI *receptacles* ($16) with 1 per circuit, because it's cheaper. Keep fridges/freezers off GFCI/AFCI if not Code required.
- AFCI protection on any wiring that seems alarmingly old; any bedroom circuits (electric blankets); and any circuits where cords are likely to get mashed against the wall by furniture.  That's what AFCI protection is for.  If the goal is to protect outlets, AFCI receps ($20) are fine since this is retrofit.
- An EV charging recep will add value to the house, so I'd throw in a 1" conduit between panel and garage. Enough room for up to 100A charging wires.
- Noting the numerous 240V breakers, it's apparent your house has electric toaster heat.  I'd **replace both that, and the A/C unit, with a wide-range heat pump** that doesn't require separate emergency heat - either straight or split unit.  That would *pay for itself* in electric bills in a few years, but not right away.
- I'd use the heat-pump dividend to replace any remaining Bryant BR's.
- I would NOT worry about the "messy panel" or seeming clutteredness of the wires.  Wires bundled tight tend to overheat and melt, so loose is better. Excess wire length **is important** so you can move breakers around in the future and/or install AFCI or GFCI... so I would not nip them off short like some of the "show panels" you see out there.  Besides, if you ever replace that panel, you're gonna want that extra length.

Comment: Thank you for the very lengthy detailed reply. Much of this is understood, conditions as such do not exist, or has already been looked at.

I watch the voltage throughout the day and rarely doe it deviate under any load condition more than a volt or 2. It runs between 121 and 123 almost 100% of the time.

And someone asked about a quality meter, yes, I have a high end Fluke tru RMS meter.

Comment: If I were to "clean up the panel I fully understand the need for length and would never cut to size. I'd always leave a "service loop" long enough to reach anywhere in the panel and then some, but neatly.
I'm definitely not saying bundle wires, I'd never do that, but i could be a little nicer. I did data cabling installs as part of a business for a long time so in my world, neatness counts.

Comment: Again, all of this is very educational and no, I do not know the actual panels well and I'm  glad I came to this forum.

I still find it odd that it won't happen for days and it usually only happens once, but last night it happened 5 times, all exactly 4 seconds. 


I did try to find BR breakers at the time and Home Depot had 'some' but not SP 15A. Maybe they were out, maybe there was a shortage at the time, IDK but whatever I read said it was OK and fully comparable to use Homeline. I guess that's competently wrong and I will replace them.

Comment: I'm not necessarily overly eager, I just want things fixed, I like things to be new and most of all I want it correct. So when someone says this is wrong or that's wrong, I'm all in on whatever it takes to make it right.


The garage isn't really used for a car, it's a little small, but maybe some day if I decide to sell. Right now I'm all about full size gas powered V8 cars and no interest in EV.


All said, I will investigate the neutral situation, as I said before and I will get the Square D breakers replaced ASAP.

Comment: Yeah, there have been a lot of breaker shortages lately, because of the building boom.  The EV charge provision isn't for you, it's for resale.  Only need it when you sell.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like a multiwire branch circuit with a neutral problem, if equally balanced in some cases devices will function going leg to leg through the neutral but if the location that is bad it the point where the 2 circuits separate (and which code now requires them to be spliced, not connected to screw terminals) the UPS senses the voltage change.

At the age of your panel these 2 circuits may not be handle tied or on a single breaker but they should be for safety if they share a single ground going out of the panel.

I would first check at the panel to verify it is a MWBC, if so go to the first box and verify the neutral connections. Over the years I have found MWBC’s with the neutrals backstabbed several times causing similar problems.
The supply neutral and one for each circuit should be a secure splice as if one of the wires is lose or arcing it will cause a problem much like you are experiencing.

Comment: I need some help on that. What is a multi-wire branch circuit?
This is pretty straight forward from my perspective, at least I think.
Drop comes to the house, goes through the meter, to an outside main disconnect breaker.
From there the feed comes into the panel you see in the pictures. There's no splitting of anything that I'm aware of anywhere.

Comment: Isn't there always only 3 conductors? Red, Black and Neutral? I don't think I've ever seen it done differently. Or are you talking about inside the panel?

Comment: There are 3 wires at the panel + ground after the first junction box electricians usually go to 2 wire +ground. So yes at the panel if it is a multi wire branch circuit wired with Romex (nm cable) it is normally red / black at the breaker. If in conduit it can be 2 blacks with a white or gray. Then when it goes to a box or device 1 hot goes 1 direction with the neutral and the other hot goes someplace but the neutrals both connect to the same white or gray wire. This point is the likely failure point.

Comment: Oooh I have to think about this now. The one circuit on the Square D breaker is new. It's a dedicated outlet circuit to my home office. New breaker, all new home run so there's shouldn't be anything funky there.
The other circuit, which is a lighting circuit was done 18 years ago and I don't recall the details. But if anything, this new outlet circuit should be 100% isolated from anything else by design.
Or are you saying this is before the panel like out in the main disconnect box by the meter?

Comment: No to me it sounds like a MWBC , exact same symptoms if the breakers have separate neutrals I would look for other code violations like 2 neutrals under 1 screw do they just happen to be under the same screw? The grounds usually can have 2 under 1 screw and in some panels 3 under 1 screw but each neutral requires its own screw. If these 2 circuits just happen to be under the same screw and it is loose it would act like a MWBC because the 2 circuits are on alternate legs creating the same problem. 
Check the neutrals  and make sure they are not the common point causing the issue at the buss.

Comment: OK, I will check that. but I have summonsed my electrician. I have always wanted to replace this panel and all the breakers simply because it's a mess and it's old, so maybe now is the time

Comment: If you can afford a replacement it would be a good idea. Get a panel with more spaces at a minimum with things like car charger sounding like they may be mandated in the future make sure if you replace to go large enough to support at least 1 additional 50 amp 240v load more than you have and you will be ahead of the game. I have been suggesting this in my area for years (not specifically 50a but that turns out to be a common charger size).

Comment: @Codewize There's nothing wrong with a BRyant panel, unless it has corroded badly.  That money could be put toward actual safety improvements like AFCI breakers.

Comment: @harper I would agree there is nothing inherently wrong with a Bryant panel other than the limited number of breaker positions, and reduced wiring space that code has allowed/ required to be increased compared to when these panels were new. They still function but that panel looks full and mis matched breakers there may be buss issues we don’t know.

Comment: OK so I did my research before buying breakers and Square D Home is supposed to be OK in Bryant panels. So I went that route. It's only those 2 brands. Whatever the original breakers are, we'll assume Bryant, and the few Square D I have installed.
I get the point on saving money and that's what my electrician said when I first asked him a few years back.
Maybe what I'll do is have someone replace all the breakers, cleaning the bus(s) and rewire / neaten things up a bit

Comment: @Codewize who said that? Not Underwriter's Laboratories. That is the voice that matters.  Not Square D either, they specifically say "don't do that".

Comment: Hmm OK, so this is the path I'm going to take. We think Square D breakers are supported, just don't mix them?
So I will have an electrician come and straighten this out.  My usual guy just told me he does not have time but I'll find someone.
Replace all the breakers with one brand / type
Get the neutrals on the neutral bus (1 per screw)
Get the grounds on the ground bus (1 per screw)
And clean whatever needs cleaning in the proccess.
Does that sound like a plan we can all agree on?

Comment: @Codewize why all the craziness here?  Why not use the correct breakers for a BR panel?  They're made by Eaton and they're called (you'll never guess this) BR.  They cost $5 each. You know how to change a breaker, just do it.............. Although I still think it's a waste of money to replace the red and blue handled BRs.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica because I can't  find a place to buy them or I would have used them to begin with.
Plus, there's obviously a no-no on the neutral / ground bus.
But OK, your voice is heard, I am listening to all input hear. Not discounting anything.
At the end I want a proper and neat panel, that's all

Comment: We are kind of off on a tangent. The question was about a pair of circuits dropping out, perhaps back to the question would better serve the site guidelines.

Comment: However we get to that point is TDB I guess but I have learned a lot here and will investigate the possibility of 2 neutrals on the same screw.

Why though does this issue cause the circuits to drop and sin't it odd that it's exactly 4 seconds every time?

I guess I am not clear on the math behind this.

Comment: Codewize, as for the reasoning I could not provide an answer without monitoring each circuit, it could be a temporary imbalance that is created when a device is turned on. But only having an issue with 2 independent circuits on separate legs we need to find out what is common. Unlikely but it could be 2 loose neutral screws. As I mentioned I have seen this with multiwire circuits on the ones with multiple neutrals the insulation was melted and there was obvious damage, several cases but not all. The breakers have nothing to do with this problem I mentioned them because they are not correct.

Comment: @Codewize, where are you that you can't get BR breakers?  Where I'm at, every big box store stocks them, and they're not too hard to order online either.  Heck, even Amazon has them: https://www.amazon.com/Cutler-Hammer-Single-Pole-Circuit-Breaker-240-Volt/dp/B00LMORID0/

Comment: Nate, I'm in Upstate NY. I have Home Depot about 1 mile from my house. The last time I checked they did not have BR breakers, it's probably been a year or so.
Lowes is about 4 miles from me, they did not have them either.
At the time I did not trust ordering online I guess because I was not familiar enough with the overall situation.
I will investigate the neutral situation tomorrow and ensure that all wires are in a dedicated screw and that none are loose
@EdBeal Noted, I will get them replaced. I will check HD and Lowes again.